# Windows PC Cannot access shared folder

Tags: windows, network-share

I need help figuring out why a PC (Windows 10) cannot access any shared folders. This happens to all users logged on to the domain joined PC. The error is "the operation being requested was not performed because the user has not been authenticated"
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Two months ago this article helps me when I was in the same spot https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/941050/error-message-on-a-windows-vista-based-computer-when-you-try-to-access-a-network-drive-that-is-mapped-to-a-web-share-the-operation-being-requested-was-not-performed-because-the-user-has-not-been-authenticated. Hope this will helps, good luck.

Comment: Referring to the link above, you can also add DWORD key with value "0" (instead of Multi-String Value) to authenticate all servers.